# How to handle touch event on UIButton added on cell of UITableView?

Tags: iphone

I m adding UIButton on each cell of UITableView dynamically. I want to handle touch event on this UIButton. Can u plz help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks In Advance,
Vikas

Answer (score 19):

```
[myCellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myCellButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I have added this statement in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView but when I touch on Button its not going in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. If I touch cell/row of UITableView outside of button it goes inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I  m not getting why  this is happening?.......How to resolve this?

Comment: You would add this target just after the `UIButton` is created, then add the button to the cell when the cell is initialized. The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is for responding to tapping the the cell (row) itself, not the button. This target action is for the button itself. Is this clearer?

Comment: I want to create UIButton on each cell of UITabelView  and  when I click on that UIButton it should change image on UIButton. So where to create UIButton for each cell &  following code so that it will work for each UIButton on every cell of UITableView.                       [myCellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myCellButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it all in code...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];        
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button sizeToFit];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];        
    }

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

...

```
- (IBAction)cellButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But I would suggest to use a UITableViewCell subclass with delegation.